# Will wonder share data recovery root the s6 and void warranty?

Tags: data-recovery

Hello i lost my important image in s6 . I have not even touched to phone with a hope that i can recover my data.  After google i saw wondershare software . It says to enable usb debugging and many thing . The thing is that will it root my phone or not ? If it root it will damage my warranty causing more trouble. So any elders can share something ???

Thank you

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37086/discussion-on-question-by-andriod-happy-user-will-wonder-share-data-recovery-roo).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Enabling USB debugging in the settings menu on the phone is not the same as getting root on the device.  USB debugging should not void your warranty, will not give you root and should not trip the KNOX flag.

Comment: In the comments OP later revealed this: "*But i was using software . I saw a message root failed due to internet connection*" and also asked it in the body of the question as "*will it root my phone or not ?*". It appears that you've not addressed it.